# Flutter - Constant flickering in the map

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I have the following issue: I'm getting the location in real time using the **Location** package, I have set the marker in the map, and when the location is updated, the map starts to flickering:https://photos.app.goo.gl/GsFdB4pHzjoUcVZ6A

The code that updates the marker location is:

```dart
subscription = location.onLocationChanged.listen((currentLocation) {
  //Update the animated marker
      setState(() {
        Marker sourceMarker = Marker(
          markerId: sourceId,
          position: LatLng(
            currentLocation.latitude,
            currentLocation.longitude,
          ),
        );
        _markers[sourceId] = sourceMarker;
   });
});
```

Comment: Can you share more code, espacially where you set the markers list to the map.

Comment: I don't have any more code. the `_locationSubsription` is set inside the initState method, and the `_markers` is declared as `final Map<MarkerId, Marker> _markers = Map<MarkerId, Marker>();`

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ??

Comment: @Nitesh I created again the view from scratch, but I post the issue in the Github issue list: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78638

Answer (score 0):

I was facing something similar and I was able to solve it.

Not sure if this will help, but still give it a try.

My code structure was something like this :

- My map was in a separate class (`ShowMap`)
- I used the `ShowMap` class on my `Home` screen with a `Stack`

And that was the entire problem.

Basically the `ShowMap` class having its own `build` method led to the flicker. So, I had to convert `ShowMap` into a `function` returning a widget.

As `ShowMap` didn't have its own `build` it was using the `build` of `Home` screen and hence the flickering stopped.

Comment: I have the same issue im gona try move to or navigate to a new view instead of my current ...unhiding it in stack..my widget has its own state and build and map only initialises and is inside that one instance. ...maybe there is a constant notify listeners . how did you find the problem ...like the affecting build that...i hope i can fix this I never had about this flickering before